# Pass DetailView Django Multiple Model in single template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

How can I pass multiple model using DetailView in single template.

my views file
views.py

```
from .models import EventDetail, EventTrainer, EventParticipant

class EventDetailView(DetailView):
    # model = EventDetail
    # template_name = 'event_templates/single_event.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass through the `context`.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(EventDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    context['event_trainers'] = EventTrainer.objects.all()
    context['event_participants'] = EventParticipants.objects.all()

    return context
```